# How to connect cloud VMs using client server in python

Tags: python, sockets, cloud, client, virtual-machine

I want to implement ring algorithm in python, on the first VM ( all my VMs are in Google Cloud) is the server part and I want many clients to connect to that server, my question is for all clients should I use the internal IP of the server for connection or each VMs internal IP for each client. Basically I don't know how to connect the clients to the server.

Comment: May I ask you, what is "ring algorithm" in your question?

Comment: yes, of course. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election  this is

Comment: I don't know Google Cloud. But as I see, all your machines require access to all your other machines (to make your election working). Imho the best for that if they are on a virtual local network, but I don't know if google cloud supports that. Probably all your instances will need an open port to connect each other. This port needs to be connectable by all other VMs.